# MPMediaQuery get local song list

Tags: ios, mpmediapickercontroller, mpmediaquery

I'm trying to get local song list from iPod music library by MPMediaQuery:

```
MPMediaQuery *everything = [[MPMediaQuery alloc] init];
NSArray *itemsFromGenericQuery = [everything items];
self.songsList = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:itemsFromGenericQuery];
```

It always return nil. But I can actually pick up music from iPod music library by **MPMediaPickerController**. Why? Can any body help? Thanks.

Comment: `MPMediaQuery *everything = [MPMediaQuery songsQuery];`? And to get Local, you can use a predicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19450392/mpmediaquery-to-return-local-items-only

Comment: @Zhou Hao Is there any way to search iTunes songs programmatically and get the song preview list.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
MPMediaQuery *mediaQuery = [MPMediaQuery songsQuery]; // run a query on song media type
[mediaQuery addFilterPredicate:[MPMediaPropertyPredicate predicateWithValue:@(NO)
                   forProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyIsCloudItem]]; // ensure what we retrieve is on device
NSArray *mediaCollections = [mediaQuery collections]; // run query
```